# W/System.err(4455): Can not deserialize instance

Tags: json, парсер, android

Пытаюсь распарсить ответ, но вылетает ексепшн:

> 03-15 09:15:48.237: W/System.err(4455): com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

```
 JsonParser jp = f.createJsonParser(sb.toString());

 List<Spot> spots = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jp,
                    new TypeReference<List<Spot>>() {
                    });
```

Json выглядит так

```
{"pool":{"Tour (1)":[{"spotid":"359en","type":"1","clientid":"0","catid":"3","langid":"1","mapiconid":"12,23","mapicon":"tour","title":"Demo-Tour Netcook","spotinfo":"Demo-Tour Netcook. This tour is for demo-purposes only.","lat":"54.851655","lon":"83.043948","distance":"0.158","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"3","website":"1","transportid":"0","caticon":"http:\/\/www.spottyguide.de\/fileadmin\/upload\/media\/images\/icons\/categories\/3.png"}],"Tourism (2)":[{"spotid":"353en","type":"0","clientid":"","catid":"7","langid":"1","mapiconid":"11","mapicon":"memorial","title":"Netcook 4","spotinfo":"Demo-Spot 4 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.852273","lon":"83.043208","distance":"0.082","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"1","website":"0","transportid":"0","caticon":"http:\/\/www.spottyguide.de\/fileadmin\/upload\/media\/images\/icons\/categories\/7.png"},{"spotid":"351en","type":"0","clientid":"0","catid":"7","langid":"1","mapiconid":"21","mapicon":"club","title":"Netcook 2","spotinfo":"Demo-Spot 2 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.853687","lon":"83.043551","distance":"0.163","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"3","website":"1","transportid":"0"}],"Partner (2)":[{"spotid":"350en","type":"0","clientid":"0","catid":"10","langid":"1","mapiconid":"11","mapicon":"memorial","title":"Netcook 1","spotinfo":" Demo-Spot 1 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.854854","lon":"83.042575","distance":"0.262","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"3","website":"1","transportid":"0","caticon":"http:\/\/www.spottyguide.de\/fileadmin\/upload\/media\/images\/icons\/categories\/10.png"},{"spotid":"355en","type":"0","clientid":"0","catid":"10","langid":"1","mapiconid":"22,28","mapicon":"shopping","title":"Netcook 6","spotinfo":"Demo-Spot 6 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.849363","lon":"83.041513","distance":"0.353","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"3","website":"1","transportid":"0"}],"Demo (10)":[{"spotid":"353en","type":"0","clientid":"","catid":"11","langid":"1","mapiconid":"11","mapicon":"memorial","title":"Netcook 4","spotinfo":"Demo-Spot 4 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.852273","lon":"83.043208","distance":"0.082","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"1","website":"0","transportid":"0","caticon":"http:\/\/www.spottyguide.de\/fileadmin\/upload\/media\/images\/icons\/categories\/11.png"},{"spotid":"359en","type":"1","clientid":"0","catid":"11","langid":"1","mapiconid":"12,23","mapicon":"tour","title":"Demo-Tour Netcook","spotinfo":"Demo-Tour Netcook. This tour is for demo-purposes only.","lat":"54.851655","lon":"83.043948","distance":"0.158","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"3","website":"1","transportid":"0"},{"spotid":"351en","type":"0","clientid":"0","catid":"11","langid":"1","mapiconid":"21","mapicon":"club","title":"Netcook 2","spotinfo":"Demo-Spot 2 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.853687","lon":"83.043551","distance":"0.163","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"3","website":"1","transportid":"0"},{"spotid":"356en","type":"0","clientid":"","catid":"11","langid":"1","mapiconid":"22,21","mapicon":"shopping","title":"Netcook 7","spotinfo":"Demo-Spot 7 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.853835","lon":"83.040504","distance":"0.174","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"2","website":"0","transportid":"0"},{"spotid":"352en","type":"0","clientid":"0","catid":"11","langid":"1","mapiconid":"23,19","mapicon":"information","title":"Netcook 3","spotinfo":"Demo-Spot 3 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.852723","lon":"83.045300","distance":"0.212","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"2","website":"1","transportid":"0"},{"spotid":"350en","type":"0","clientid":"0","catid":"11","langid":"1","mapiconid":"11","mapicon":"memorial","title":"Netcook 1","spotinfo":" Demo-Spot 1 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.854854","lon":"83.042575","distance":"0.262","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"3","website":"1","transportid":"0"},{"spotid":"357en","type":"0","clientid":"0","catid":"11","langid":"1","mapiconid":"22,28","mapicon":"shopping","title":"Netcook 8","spotinfo":"Demo-Spot 8 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.854552","lon":"83.045965","distance":"0.340","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"4","website":"1","transportid":"0"},{"spotid":"358en","type":"0","clientid":"0","catid":"11","langid":"1","mapiconid":"21","mapicon":"club","title":"Netcook 9","spotinfo":"Demo-Spot 9 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.850241","lon":"83.045697","distance":"0.347","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"3","website":"1","transportid":"0"},{"spotid":"355en","type":"0","clientid":"0","catid":"11","langid":"1","mapiconid":"22,28","mapicon":"shopping","title":"Netcook 6","spotinfo":"Demo-Spot 6 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.849363","lon":"83.041513","distance":"0.353","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"3","website":"1","transportid":"0"},{"spotid":"354en","type":"0","clientid":"0","catid":"11","langid":"1","mapiconid":"39","mapicon":"parking","title":"Netcook 5","spotinfo":"Demo-Spot 5 for Netcook. This spot was made for demo purposes only.","lat":"54.848412","lon":"83.047521","distance":"0.578","starttime":"0","endtime":"0","accessibility":"3","website":"1","transportid":"0"}]}}
```

И моделька для него

```
public class Spot  {
@DatabaseField(id=true)
@JsonProperty("spotid")
public String spotId;
@JsonProperty("type")
public int type;
@JsonProperty("clientid")
public int clientId;
@JsonProperty("catid")
public int catId;
@JsonProperty("langid")
public int langId;
@JsonProperty("mapiconid")
public int mapIconId;
@JsonProperty("mapicon")
public String mapIcon;
@DatabaseField(columnName = "title", canBeNull = false)
@JsonProperty("title")
public String title;
@DatabaseField(columnName = "spotInfo", canBeNull = false)
@JsonProperty("spotinfo")
public String spotInfo;
@JsonProperty("lat")
public float lat;
@JsonProperty("lon")
public float lon;
@JsonProperty("distance")
public float distance;
@JsonProperty("starttime")
public String startTime;
@JsonProperty("endtime")
public String endTime;
@JsonProperty("accessibility")
public float accessibility;
@JsonProperty("transportid")
public int tansportId;

public String favorite;
@JsonProperty("website")
public String uri;
public String category;

public Bitmap image;

public boolean roadbook;
public boolean target;

public boolean icon1;
public boolean icon2;
public boolean icon3;
public boolean icon4;
public boolean icon5;
public boolean icon6;
```

}

Comment: У вас парсер ожидает JSON-массив, а получает JSON-объект, как результат - исключение. Проще говоря, аннотированная модель и сам JSON друг другу не соответствуют.

Comment: http://dajver.blogspot.com/2013/02/json.html

Comment: Я знаю что не соответствует. Почти сразу понял.Но не могли вы меня отправить по какой-нибудь ссылке где описано как самому сделать кастомный парсе для того что мне нужно?

Comment: Простите,не заметил вашу ссылку.Спасибо!В процессе прочтения!)

Comment: Нет,там также как и везде где я смотрел.Понимаете,эти объекты которые приходят после главного объекта Pool.Их названия тоже меняются,но везде где осущ доступ к объектам только по их названию.А я можно сказать этих названий не знаю.Никакого доступа по индексам я не нашёл.Так что же делать?

Comment: Немного разобрался
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
 JSONObject urls = json.getJSONObject("pool");

дальше двигаюсь по ключам urls.keys().next()
Но проблема в том что json  переменная содержит вовсе не весь этот json string(sb.toString),а {"pool":  и самый последний объект Demo и у него в массиве всё перемешано.Почему так могло случится?
В sb всё верно хранится,весь json string.Проверял.

Comment: Я полностью разобрался как распарсить всё это дело,но проблема осталась та же JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
в нём в итоге лежит не вся строка(((

Answer (score 1):

Этот Json сформирован автоматом и получен из отладчика?
Т.е. 100% это именно то, что приходит маперу?

Тут народ об это тоже зубы ломал:
[Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider/issues/1)

Рекоммендую изучить

Comment: да,он приходит с сервера.Я выводил логи

Comment: Эту ссылку я тоже уже мильон) раз просматривал)